# Script that launch everytime I type a certain command

Tags: linux, ssh, script

So basically each time a user use the command ssh I want to launch a script that fetch the user name and time he typed it with the ipaddress he want to ssh to and send them to the server he is trying to ssh to.

Is this possible? and what command can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Alias `ssh` to a script that does what you want.

Comment: See my answer for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on a 'nix based machine, you could use this script:

```
# ssh script to grab username, date/time, and destination

first=`echo "$*" | cut -d "@" -f 1`
last=`echo "$*" | cut -d "@" -f 2`

time=`date`
ip=`echo $last | cut -d " " -f 1`
user=`echo $first | rev | cut -d " " -f 1 | rev`

echo "At $time, $USER on $HOSTNAME attempted to ssh to $user@$ip" >> sshlog.txt

ssh $*

endtime=`date`
echo "At $endtime, $USER on $HOSTNAME exited an ssh session to $user@$ip" >> sshlog.txt
```

Just alias ssh to the location of this script, e.g. `alias ssh=/home/bob/bin/ssh` and everything should work.

Comment: Daniel! thank you! worked perfectly my problem was forgetting the ssh at the end.. Do you know how to send a same message when the user exit the ssh ? is there a way to do that as well ? so the log will store when the user logged in and when he logged out

Comment: I will edit to give that info

Comment: There.  Also, keep in mind that if you remove the `>> sshlog.txt` from those echo lines, that information will be displayed onscreeen.

Comment: Well you would be the first girl that ever took interest in me.